# How to re-enable the context menu in this case?

Tags: javascript, events, contextmenu

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.returnValue = false
    e.cancleBubble = true
})
```

No way?

Edit: `document.oncontextmenu = null` does not work.

P.S. I cannot have the reference of the listener function since I am not the owner of the site preventing the context menu.

Comment: what do you mean by "ethics"?

Comment: Sites that purposely disable the context menu deserve to have their scripts suppressed or not ran, in my opinion. (I use NoScript.) I often navigate by right-clicking and selecting Back or Forward. There is nothing unethical about wanting the context menu to work. The site author disabling it in the first place is stupid.

Comment: Have you tried `document.oncontextmenu = null;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are **really** desperate, try adding this before the `addEventListener` is called. It works in both FF and Chrome. I didn't check anything else.

```
document.superListener = document.addEventListener;
document.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture){
    if(type != 'contextmenu')
        document.superListener(type, listener, !!useCapture);
};
```

It may not be the best way to do things, but it should be the job done on your specific example :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that it is impossible to re-enable the context menu "after" the call...

Answer (score 23):

I use my bookmarklet in such cases:

```
javascript:(function(w){
    var arr = ['contextmenu','copy','cut','paste','mousedown','mouseup','beforeunload','beforeprint'];
    for(var i = 0, x; x = arr[i]; i++){
        if(w['on' + x])w['on' + x] = null;
        w.addEventListener(x, function(e){e.stopPropagation()}, true);
    };
    for(var j = 0, f; f = w.frames[j]; j++){try{arguments.callee(f)}catch(e){}}})(window);
```

Comment: This one worked fine. Just had to limit the options to 'contextmenu'.

Comment: `'copy','cut','paste','mousedown','mouseup','beforeunload','beforeprint'` do not work though `'contextmenu'` works for site `https://verification.taxofficemanagement.gov.bd/`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than disabling the context menu, why don't you assign the right click event?

http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin/

Comment: I'm not the one who disables the context menu. Some sites disable it, and I want to break it.

Comment: Oh, do you mean as a greasemonkey script or something?