# How to allow right click for some elements if It is disabled through java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`document.oncontextmenu=function(){
 return false;
};`

Right click is disabled on my website,I want to enable it for a modal which will show an Image to download.

Comment: pls add some relevant code to start with or people will delete your question.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230622/disable-enable-right-click-on-a-particular-part-of-the-html-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230622/disable-enable-right-click-on-a-particular-part-of-the-html-body)  Easy to find info on this topic with a little research.

Comment: In general, it isn't great to disable right-click anyway.  Consider not doing that, unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Right click at the document level is usually disabled by something like

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can stop the propagation of the event at the element you want and never let the bubbling event reach the document level.

```
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note that this only works if `preventDefault()` was set in the event [bubble](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) phase and not in the `capture` phase.